# RAILS - Why Puma server is taking too long to respond?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I'm trying to change some CSS/SCSS file at my project, the local server (puma) takes too long time to load the page. I'm having this

```
  Rendering printlists/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered partials/_sidebar.html.erb (109.0ms)
  Rendered printlists/_template.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered printlists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (439.0ms)
Started GET "/printlists/13.pdf" for ::1 at 2017-05-31 16:24:04 -0300
Processing by PrintlistsController#show as PDF
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  User Load (161.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
***************WICKED***************
  Rendering printlists/show.pdf.erb
Completed 200 OK in 131907ms (Views: 131866.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Completed 200 OK in 132401ms (Views: 132275.3ms | ActiveRecord: 79.0ms)


  Rendered printlists/_template.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered printlists/show.pdf.erb (81306.7ms)
"***************[\"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe\", \"--encoding\", \"UTF-8\", \"--foo
ter-center\", \"Center\", \"--footer-left\", \"Left\", \"--footer-right\", \"Right\", \"file:///C:/Users/
EVOLUT~1/AppData/Local/Temp/wicked_pdf20170531-6104-vll9bs.html\", \"C:/Users/EVOLUT~1/AppData/Local/Temp
/wicked_pdf_generated_file20170531-6104-1yg9cbt.pdf\"]***************"
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data file.pdf.pdf (99.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 83474ms (Views: 98.9ms | ActiveRecord: 210.0ms)


Completed 200 OK in 143922ms (Views: 143651.0ms | ActiveRecord: 153.0ms)


Completed 200 OK in 140215ms (Views: 139404.1ms | ActiveRecord: 186.0ms)
```

**All my stylesheets are there, `main.scss` are importing all the files on `estilos's folder`**

```
---- application.scss
---- base
---- bootstrap_and_overrides.css
---- documents.css.scss
---- estilos
------- contato.scss
------- dashboard.scss
------- download.scss
------- home.scss
------- loginprograma.scss
------- pgt.scss
------- pgtcheckout.scss
------- posters.css.scss
------- programa.scss
------- servico.scss
------- sobres.scs
---- main.scss
---- scaffolds.scss
```

**main.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "base/modules/variables";

@import "base/mixins.scss";
@import "base/normalize.scss";
@import "base/globals.scss";
@import "estilos/home.scss";
@import "estilos/servico.scss";
@import "estilos/sobres.scss";
@import "estilos/contato.scss";
@import "estilos/download.scss";
@import "estilos/programa.scss";
@import "estilos/dashboard.scss";
@import "estilos/pgtcheckout.scss";
@import "estilos/posters.css.scss";
@import "documents.css.scss";
```

**development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end


  config.assets.debug = true
```

When I'm trying to change some CSS/SCSS file at my project, the local server (puma) takes too long time to load the page. How can I fix it?

Comment: It means every time you make a change to your stylesheets, rails assets pipeline is recompiling all sheets affected.  You need to make sure you're not trying to load too many stylesheets/js libraries.  Make sure any styles being compiled are actually needed.

Comment: Are you using iFrames to render those PDFs?

Comment: No Aaron, i'm not. But even when I didn't have to render these PDFs, I was having the same problem.

Comment: Do you have [quiet assets](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) enabled? You might try disabling that to add some logging regarding your assets. If you're using Rails 5, the [options have changed](https://rossta.net/blog/quiet-assets-in-rails-5.html).

Comment: Yes, I do have it enabled. I`m using Rails 5.0.2